# NTFS partition alteration or removal

Tags: windows-xp, ntfs, boot-partition

My PC has one disk divided into 2 partitions. The second (which in Disk Management is referred to as 'Boot'and 'Logical') appears to contain the OS although there is a WINDOWS folder on the larger partition (labelled as 'System and Primary'). 
The smaller one is extremely short of space and I am trying to remove the partition or change them over so that the larger one is the main drive. Being virtually useless with technology I would appreciate any advice.
*As a new user I am not able to add screenshots, however I am going to try the other suggestions, thank you.*
Sorry, haven't quite got the hang of this forum, the way replies/posts and edits work.

Comment: Please add a screen shot to understand it clearly.

Comment: Does the larger partition have more free space?  PS to add an image to your question, press CTR and G together.  If you don't know how to take a screen shot, [this site](http://www.geekpolice.net/t20825-how-to-take-a-screenshot-upload-attach-it-to-posts) may help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot non-destructively modify partitions from within Windows XP – especially not if they contain the operating system itself. (In [Microsoft's backwards terminology](http://www.ubuntu.com/), the "boot" volume contains the operating system itself, and the "system" volume only has the bootloader.)

However, you can use GParted from a "live CD" to resize the partitions; an [Ubuntu Linux](http://www.ubuntu.com/) CD might be easier to make ([instructions](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu/download)), although there is a bare [GParted Live](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/livecd.php) as well. After booting from the CD, open GParted and use the "Resize" function.